# rails 2.3.4 "Template is missing" when using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to make it work?

I have a file index.html.haml
and a index.html.erb. the erb one works, then when i delete the erb, it gives me the template is missing error.

I have rails 2.3.4 and installed the haml gem.

"Template is missing
Missing template profiles/index.erb in view path app/views"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need a run `haml --rails yourproject` which will install a initalizer in `vender/plugins/haml`.

Comment: it gives me: Directory Tests01/vendor/plugins doesn't exist

Comment: the create `Tests01/vendor/plugins` first

Comment: the problem is that already exists. I think is not looking in my workspace folder. im using aptana and eclipse

Comment: already done it using the absolute path.
now it works. thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Add `config.gem "haml"` to your `Rails::Initializer.run` block in your envrionment.rb file.  The old `haml --rails yourproject` is being phazed out.